# icanhazstring/composer-unused (installed globally) contains a Composer plug in which is blocked by your allow-plugins config

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm, php-8.1

When I try to run "Composer > Install" from PhpStorm I get the following error:

> In PluginManager.php line 762:
>
> icanhazstring/composer-unused (installed globally) contains a Composer
> plug in which is blocked by your allow-plugins config. You may add it
> to the list if you consider it safe.
>
> You can run `composer global config --no-plugins allow-plugins.icanhazstring/composer-unused [true|false]` to enable it
> (true) or disable it explicitly and suppress this exception (false)
> See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins

What might be the reason for this error message above?

I have tried to run

```
/etc/php8/bin/php composer.phar global config --no-plugins allow-plugins.icanhazstrin  true
```

and I have also tried to add the following to the `composer.json` file

```json
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": true,
```

but still I get the same error message.

My `composer.json` is something like:

```json
{
    "name": "test/version1",
    "description":"Test Version 1",
    "keywords":[],
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": true,
        "secure-http":false
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit --config tests/phpunit.xml"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.3",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.26.*",

...

    "require-dev": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.16",
        "icanhazstring/composer-unused": "^0.7.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would explicitly list that plugin as allowed in the actual composer.json `"config": { "allow-plugins": { "icanhazstring/composer-unused": true } },` . Cannot say why `"allow-plugins": true` is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

```
/etc/php8/bin/php composer.phar global show -i
```

Then it will ask if you want to trust `icanhazstring/composer-unused`. Type `y` and press the enter button. That's it.

Then if you go to `/home/yourUbuntuUsername/.config/composer/` there you will see another `composer.json` file with the following content:

```
{
    "require": {
        "icanhazstring/composer-unused": "^0.7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "icanhazstrin": true,
            "icanhazstring/composer-unused": true
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently there is something called global Composer packages

Comment: Just a note: this `"icanhazstrin": true,` line seems to be wrong. I mean: it has no `g` at the end (as in `icanhazstring/composer-unused`). Right now I think it might be because of the command that you have run earlier in your question `composer.phar global config ...` .. which looks wrong in that aspect as compared to the command from the error message...